# Dbunit data set and primary key problems

Tags: java, h2, dbunit

I have updated version of Hibernate from 4 to 5, and of that time, I have problems with dbunit and datasets in tests.

@DatabaseSetup is used to load XML data for the tests to the h2 DB, data is loaded fine.
Example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>
   <table1 my_id="1" someOtherParam="p1" />
   <table1 my_id="2" someOtherParam="p2" />
</dataset>
```

Retrieval of data works fine, and I can retrieve all the data so dbunit is working fine, but inserting of data is failing as on insert of new data by using entity of a table1 that has primary key generated id

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = SEQ_mySequence) )
```

Problem is that on insert, hibernate is trying to get id based on sequence and it is always 1 :(
And then there is a problem of insertion and primary key violation.

Any idea how to fix this. The main change was just upgrading of Hibernate from 4 to 5.

Thx

Comment: `SEQ_mySequence` - where you defined your sequence?

Comment: @ByeBye
It is defined in table definition and in entity class